# I can't make a SSH tunnel successfully inside a docker container

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, docker, nat

So far I have had a home server where I use [this technique](http://xmodulo.com/access-linux-server-behind-nat-reverse-ssh-tunnel.html) to access it outside home.

But now I have other requirement, I want to make this from a docker container inside my home server. But if I try to connect to the tunnel I get a connection refused error.

So, in order to setup something like this, I have a VPS online, and my home server. Inside my home server I have a container running. I exchange the public keys between the VPS and the container, by properly configuring the `authorized_keys` file in each other. I have confirmed that I am running the container with `-p 22:22`, and that no SSH service is running outside the container that could be using the host's port 22.

Then I run this command in the container:

`$ ssh -vvvfN -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -R 20007:localhost:22 myvps@myvpsdomain.com`

Then in my VPS I type this and the output is followed

```
$ ssh -vvv container_user@localhost -p 20007
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 20009
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 20009.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/raspi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Now, when I check the container logs, this is what I see:

```
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com 
want_reply 0
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 20007, connect localhost:22
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 20007, originator 127.0.0.1 port 60364
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([::1]:22) in progress, fd=7
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [127.0.0.1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug3: channel 0: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 0: connection failed: Connection refused
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 8 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) in progress, fd=8
debug3: channel 0: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 0: connection failed: Connection refused
connect_to localhost port 22: failed.
debug2: channel 0: zombie
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: 127.0.0.1, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
```

Remember that all these steps work perfectly when run outside a container, but somehow, inside the container the VPS cannot make the connection using the tunnel...

**EDIT**: Here is the code of the container making the tunnel to the remote server:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh htop nano autossh
RUN ssh-keygen -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N '';                                             \
COPY authorized_keys $HOME/.ssh/
echo '=======SAVE THIS KEY TO ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the Cloud Server=======';             \
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub;                                                                    \
echo '=========================================================================';

RUN sleep 20 # Give me time to put the key in the cloud server

RUN echo "/usr/bin/ssh -vvvfN -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -R 20009:localhost:22 myvps@myvpsdomain.com" > $HOME/connect.sh; \
chmod 777 $HOME/connect.sh

EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 20009
CMD ["sh", "-c", "$HOME/connect.sh"]
```

> This Dockerfile:
>
> - generates a key pair,
> - stores the pub key of the remote server,
> - waits 20 secs for me to put that key pair in the remote server authorized_keys,
> - and then opens the tunnel.
>
> It doesn't work well as you can see for the error messages. But if I
>   do these exact same steps in a physical machine instead of a container
>   it just works fine...